# read,add and update sharepoint 2010 list from an asp.net application

Tags: rest, web-services, asp.net

I have a sharepoint site which is internal and I would like to build a website that is public to get some data from a list in this sharepoint 2010 instance.

The asp.net site would be hosted publicly.

In terms of security and permission would it be possible using web services,rest or object model.

Can I easily pass a specific credentials to be able to by pass the access layer on the fly?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Who are the users for the public facing site? Are they same as internal users? Why not a build the list as a table in SQL DB and have that available as external list in SharePoint?

Comment: Thanks Vamsi.
The users are public and it has to be anonymous.I want to hook directly to sharepoint list dont want any extra tables etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call SharePoint web services from server side & then user Credentials to the webservice client object & then do your operations. The credentials you can store it in your web.config file

Refer:
[Adding webservice reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx), then for credentials 
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx), 
[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers)